# SQL Query with MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jersey, jax-rs

I am implementing a Restful Web Service in java (JAX-RS) using Jesey. I run it on Tomcat v7.0 I use Hibernate to map the data to the database (MySQL). I have a query to fetch the list of deliverable:

```
deliverables = (List<Deliverable>) session.createQuery("Select deliverable from
                Task as t where t.project.id= :id And t.user.username = :name")
    .setLong("id", projectId).setString("name", username).list();
```

It is giving me a hundred of deliverables, but I want to have TOP three in Task table. I appreciate for any help. How can I modify the query?

Note that these three deliverables should not be repetitive.

There was a conflict with @FGreg answer. When I use these queries, everything works fine:

```
deliverables = (List<Deliverable>) session.createQuery(
    "from Deliverable as d where d.project.id= :id").setLong("id", projectId).list();
    long task_id;
    for(Deliverable d: deliverables) {
        task_id =  (long) session.createQuery("Select Max(id) from Task as t where     
        t.deliverable.id = :id and t.user.username = :name")
        .setLong("id", d.getId()).setString("name", username).uniqueResult();
         d.setTask_id(task_id);
    }
    sortDeliverable(deliverables);   // sort by Task_id
```

I think in the query provided by @FGreg, the max(id) is not considered for example a deliverable is used two times with task_id = 31, 643. It may consider the Task_id = 31, which is wrong. Any help to fix it?

I tried @FGreg query without distinct. Then it works fine except repetition problem.

I tried this:

```
deliverables = (List<Deliverable>) session.createQuery("from Deliverable as d inner join 
 Task as t where t.id = (select max(t1.id) from Task as t1 where t1.deliverable.id = d.id)   
 and d.project.id= :id and t.user.username = :name order by t.id desc")
                    .setMaxResults(3)
                    .setLong("id", projectId)
                    .setString("name", username)
                    .list();
```

And I got New Error in the stack trace:

```
Jul 13, 2012 5:03:10 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  Path expected for join!
Jul 13, 2012 5:03:10 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  Path expected for join!
 Path expected for join!
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3477)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3263)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3141)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:694)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:550)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1537)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:350)
    at $Proxy65.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at se.softwerk.timelog.controller.DeliverableManager.deliverableList2(DeliverableManager.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jul 13, 2012 5:03:10 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  Invalid path: 't.id'
Jul 13, 2012 5:03:10 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  Invalid path: 't.id'
 Invalid path: 't.id'
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.lookupConstant(LiteralProcessor.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:883)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1246)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4252)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3730)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1923)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1848)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1848)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:583)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1537)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:350)
    at $Proxy65.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at se.softwerk.timelog.controller.DeliverableManager.deliverableList2(DeliverableManager.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

The Model classes:

```
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Project project;


    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Deliverable deliverable;
}
```

And Deliverable:

```
@Entity
public class Deliverable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "short", nullable = false)
    private String key;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Task.class, mappedBy = "deliverable", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Task> tasks;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project")
    private Project project;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
    private Deliverable parent;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Deliverable.class, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Deliverable> children;
}
```

Comment: I raised up a new question that may be helpful to solve this problem. Check it out please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457292/sql-query-using-hibernate-in-a-restful-web-service

Comment: That error suggests there may be a problem with your Hibernate mapping between the two objects. Make sure you have the `<one-to-many>` and `<many-to-one>` tags in your mapping file correctly. My edit below should work regardless if you have this mapped or not.

Comment: I think that <one-to-many> and <many-to-one> tags in the mapping file works correctly. I checked them several times.

Comment: I have added the Mapping classes at the end of the question. Is there any problem there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking for the top 3 `Deliverable`s from `Task` ordered by ID. You could try something like this:

**Edit:** Ok I'll take one more stab at this. This should give you the top 3 `Deliverable`s ordered by `Task.id` taking only the `Deliverable` associated to the `max(Task.id)`

```
deliverables = 
        (List<Deliverable>) session.createQuery(
            "from Deliverable as d, Task as t
                where t.deliverable.id = d.id and
                t.id = (select max(t1.id) from Task t1 where t1.deliverable.id = d.id)
                and d.project.id= :id
                and t.user.username = :name
                order by t.id desc")
        .setMaxResults(3)
        .setLong("id", projectId)
        .setString("name", username)
        .list();
```

Comment: Good help. I ask the question in a way that you misunderstood. I am editing it now. But I guess it is so close to what I want. ( these three deliverable should not be repetitive.)

Comment: I appreciate again. There was a conflict, I edited the question, would you please check it.

Comment: It was a real useful Edit. But I got an error again. I have no clue why. I just copy the error from stack trace to the end of the question. Maybe because of  (... = (select max(t1.id) from Task t1 where t1.deliverable.id = d.id) ) It may not supported in Jersey

Comment: I have added the Mapping classes at the end of the question. Is there any problem there?

Answer (score 2):

mysql doesn't have TOP, use the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses at the end of the sql.

Comment: I checked with my friend @ali, Barmar is correct. try to explore how to use LIMIT.

Comment: @ali: now check Barmar answer, I add an example for how use LIMIT.

Comment: I try LIMIT, it did not work for me. But I guess if it works the result is the same like @FGerg response. ".setMaxResults(3)" also make the same result.

Comment: As I said in the question : "these three items should not be repetitive". That's why @FGreg suggested distinct function. The problem was what I added to the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure TOP function is available in mysql but try to use it and share the result. you can write like this:
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Persons

check this link, it will furnish you with more details.
[enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

Comment: I appreciate, No TOP function is not supported in mysql.