# SQL Query using Hibernate in a Restful Web Service

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jersey, jax-rs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Query with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441313/sql-query-with-mysql)

I implement a Rest Web Service (JAX-RS) using Jersey in Java. I use hibernate to fetch the data from MySQL database. 
With this query:

```
(Select distinct deliverable.id from Task as t where t.project.id= :id And t.user.username = :name order by t.id desc")
                    .setMaxResults(3)
                    .setLong("id", projectId)
                    .setString("name", username)
                    .list();
```

I have a right result which is : [275,51,286]. This is the provided key for every id in the database:

```
    id       key
---------------------
    275      2.0
    51       cm
    286      19.87
```

Now I use this query (Everything is the same except deliverable.key instead of deliverable.id) :

```
(Select distinct deliverable.key from Task as t where t.project.id= :id And t.user.username = :name order by t.id desc")
                    .setMaxResults(3)
                    .setLong("id", projectId)
                    .setString("name", username)
                    .list();
```

The result is: ["2.0","19.88","19.99"]. The first one is right, but the second and third one are completely different keys.

Maybe it can be solved by "alias" or any other way. your suggestion?

Comment: I think you'll find that if you take away the .setMaxResults, you're getting the right results, just in a different order.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I need to have it exactly in this order. and then Fetch the Top three, that's why I used .setMaxResults. Do you have any idea how can I modify the query?

Comment: But what order is that? You're not being very explicit. Try something like `ORDER BY t.id, deliverable.id` for both queries, or whichever order you want it in.

Comment: I did it, Take a look at the queries. We have order by t.id desc

Comment: But you're not specifying an order for 'deliverable'. That's like expecting `SELECT lastname, firstname FROM user ORDER BY lastname` to order by firstname also, even though you didn't specify it. When you don't specify the order, the order is arbitrary.

Comment: I tried (ORDER BY t.id, deliverable.id). it does not work. I just want to add in the first query if I don't use .setMaxResults, the results is close to hundred of ids. But with just (ORDER BY t.id), it's perfectly working. So it should not be arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
("select d.key from Deliverable as d, Task as t
                where t.deliverable.id = d.id and
                t.id = (select max(t1.id) from Task t1 where t1.deliverable.id = d.id)
                and d.project.id= :id
                and t.user.username = :name
                order by t.id desc")
        .setMaxResults(3)
        .setLong("id", projectId)
        .setString("name", username)
        .list();
```